# Android statement similar to "for each" for RadioGroup

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have a RadioGroup on one of my Android screens with several buttons in it. I want to modify the text of all of these buttons with a certain method. Is there some way I can loop through each button, or do I have to write a line of code for each one?

I am using Xamarin, but Java answers are welcome as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that using `foreach` but you can using a traditional `for loop`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < radioGroup.ChildCount; i ++)
{
    RadioButton radioButton =  (RadioButton)radioGroup.GetChildAt(i);
}
```